# added subview won't show after the app relaunch

Tags: iphone, window, subview

I have a subview added on app relaunch, on the applicationDidBecomeActive got called, but it's not shown, what could be the reason?

```
- (UIView *)mySubView {
    if (_mySubView == nil) {
       _mySubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       _mySubView.opaque = NO;
       _mySubView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
       _mySubView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
       [_mySubView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }

    return _mySubView;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
    [window addSubview:[self mySubView]];
}
```

What's more interesting is that - it'll shown if I leave the app launched, turn off the device, then turn the device back on. But if I close the app, then relaunch it, I won't be able to see the subview.

Comment: I am still seeing the same behavior after trying with the solutions provided by Ecarrion and Hardic, don't understand why it's such weird behavior on relaunch, comepare to the other scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following line like this,

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application     
{

   UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];

   [window addSubview:[self mySubView]];

   [window makeKeyAndVisible];

 }
```

and also change the color `[UIColor blueColor];`

You will see the effect sure

Enjoy!

Comment: It doesn't seem to help, I am still seeing the same behavior. Could it be somehow covered by the viewcontrollers that got loaded after the addSubview call is made? If so, is there a deterministic way to overcome that situation?

Answer (score 1):

IF you're on your App delegate and you have a window property, as you should have, you could just simply do this:

```
[[self window] addSubview:[self mySubView]];
```

For setting the window property do this:

In your AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

In your AppDelegate.m - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

.
.
.
//Create your main controller
.
.
.

[self.window setRootViewController:mainController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I don't have a window property on my app delegate. How could I get/set it? Otherwise, it crashed when referencing the window property.